# Convert XLSX file to XLSB using Java or Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

i am using apache poi library to create xlsx file using java code.
not as new requirement i need to create xlsx files with lots of data. so i am thinking about xlsb file format. but i didnt find any way to create xlsb file using apache poi. or any other way to convert xlsx file format to xlsb file .
 here i am posting my code to create xlsx file using apache poi

```
try {
                    outputFile = File.createTempFile("Dept_Wise_Invoice_Details-", ".xlsx");
                    OutputStream out = null;
                    out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                    SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(2000);
                    SXSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1") ;

                    //iterating r number of rows
                    SXSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);
                    for (int c=0;c < model.getColumnCount()-2; c++ ) //-2
                    {
                        SXSSFCell cell = header.createCell(c);
                        cell.setCellValue(model.getColumnName(c).toString());
                    }

                    for (int r=0;r <row1.size() ; r++ )
                    {

                    SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r+1);

                    //iterating c number of columns
                    for (int c=0;c < model.getColumnCount()-2; c++ ) //-2
                    {
                    SXSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
                    try
                    {
                    cell.setCellValue(model.getValueAt(Integer.parseInt(row1.get(r).toString()), c).toString());
                    }
                    catch(Exception eee)
                    {
                        //eee.printStackTrace();
                        cell.setCellValue("");  
                    }
                    }
                    }
```

OR CAN CREATE XLSB FILE USING APATCHE POI?

Comment: is there any external way (without apatche poi) to achieve my requirement? please help

Comment: Why do you want a `.xlsb` file? What advantage do you think it gives you? (Mostly it just introduces additional problems....)

Comment: Apache POI doesn't support the .xlsb file format execpt for text extraction

Comment: i want to attach those files to outlook email through my  java application. so i just want to ensure that the file size would be lesser